# How to delete a line starting with Specific String but keeping a speific word in that line?

Tags: awk, sed, fasta

I have gene sequence file and I would like to change the header of each gene. Here is the input:

```
>lcl|CP000046.1_cds_AAW37389.1_1 [gene=dnaA] [locus_tag=SACOL0001] [protein=chromosomal replication initiator protein DnaA] [protein_id=AAW37389.1] [location=544..1905] [gbkey=CDS]
ATGTCGGAAAAAGAAATTTGGGAAAAAGTGCTTGAAATTGCTCAAGAAAAATTATCAGCTGTAAGTTACTCAACTTTCCTAAAAGATACTGAGCTTTACACGATTAAAGATGGTGAAGCTATCGTATTATCGAGTATTCCTTTTAATGCAAATTGGTTAAATCAACAATATGCTGAAATTATCCAAGCAATCTTATTTGATGTTGTAGGCTATGAAGTTAAACCTCACTTTATTACTCTGAAGAATTAGCAAATTATAGTAATAATGAAACTGCTACTCCAAAAGAAACAACAAAACCTTCTACTGAAACAACTGAGGATAATCATGTGCTTGGTAGAGAGCAATTCAATGCCCATAACACATTTGACACTTTTGTAATCGGACCCGGTAACCGCTTTCCACATGCAGCGAGTTTAGCTGTGGCCGAAGCACCAGCCAAAGCGTACAATCCATTATTTATCTATGGAGGTGTTGGTTTA

>lcl|CP000046.1_cds_AAW37390.1_2 [gene=dnaN] [locus_tag=SACOL0002] [protein=DNA polymerase III, beta subunit] [protein_id=AAW37390.1] [location=2183..3316] [gbkey=CDS]
ATGATGGAATTCACTATTAAAAGAGATTATTTTATTACACAATTAAATGACACATTAAAAGCTATTTCACCAAGAACAACATTACCTATATTAACTGGTATCAAAATCGATGCGAAAGAACATGAAGTTATATTAACTGGTTCAGACTCTGAAATTTCAATAGAAATCACTATTCCTAAAACTGTAGATGGCGAAGATATTGTCAATATTTCAGAAACAGGCTCAGTAGTACTTCCTGGACGATTCTTTGTTGATATTATAAAAAAATTACCTGGTAAAGATGTTAAATTATCTACAAATGAACAATTCCAGACATTAATTACATCAGGTCATTCTGAATTTAATTTAAGTGGCTTAGATCCAGATCAATATCCTTTATTACCTCAAGTTTCTAGAGATG
```

Expected Output:

```
>Saureus1|SACOL0001
ATGTCGGAAAAAGAAATTTGGGAAAAAGTGCTTGAAATTGCTCAAGAAAAATTATCAGCTGTAAGTTACTCAACTTTCCTAAAAGATACTGAGCTTTACACGATTAAAGATGGTGAAGCTATCGTATTATCGAGTATTCCTTTTAATGCAAATTGGTTAAATCAACAATATGCTGAAATTATCCAAGCAATCTTATTTGATGTTGTAGGCTATGAAGTTAAACCTCACTTTATTACTCTGAAGAATTAGCAAATTATAGTAATAATGAAACTGCTACTCCAAAAGAAACAACAAAACCTTCTACTGAAACAACTGAGGATAATCATGTGCTTGGTAGAGAGCAATTCAATGCCCATAACACATTTGACACTTTTGTAATCGGACCCGGTAACCGCTTTCCACATGCAGCGAGTTTAGCTGTGGCCGAAGCACCAGCCAAAGCGTACAATCCATTATTTATCTATGGAGGTGTTGGTTTA

>Saureus1|SACOL0002
ATGATGGAATTCACTATTAAAAGAGATTATTTTATTACACAATTAAATGACACATTAAAAGCTATTTCACCAAGAACAACATTACCTATATTAACTGGTATCAAAATCGATGCGAAAGAACATGAAGTTATATTAACTGGTTCAGACTCTGAAATTTCAATAGAAATCACTATTCCTAAAACTGTAGATGGCGAAGATATTGTCAATATTTCAGAAACAGGCTCAGTAGTACTTCCTGGACGATTCTTTGTTGATATTATAAAAAAATTACCTGGTAAAGATGTTAAATTATCTACAAATGAACAATTCCAGACATTAATTACATCAGGTCATTCTGAATTTAATTTAAGTGGCTTAGATCCAGATCAATATCCTTTATTACCTCAAGTTTCTAGAGATG
```

I know how to delete a line congaing specific word with sed

```
sed '/^>/ d' inputfile > outputfile
```

But I am not getting any Idea to get the expected output. Here, in first part I should delete all the text in the gene header except SACOL00 and later preceding that I should keep fasta sysmbol ">" with Strain name.

If this kind of question repeated please excuse me.

Comment: Please use code tags for your samples shown rather than quote tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -E 's/^>.*locus_tag=([^]]*).*/Saureus1|\1/' file
```

With sed:

```
sed 's/^>.*locus_tag=\([^]]*\).*/Saureus1|\1/' file
```

---

See: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Answer (score 1):

**`Awk`** solution:

```
awk '/^>lcl/{ gsub(/^\[[^=]+=|\]$/,"",$3); printf ">Saureus1|%s\n",$3; next }1' file
```

The output:

```
>Saureus1|SACOL0001
ATGTCGGAAAAAGAAATTTGGGAAAAAGTGCTTGAAATTGCTCAAGAAAAATTATCAGCTGTAAGTTACTCAACTTTCCTAAAAGATACTGAGCTTTACACGATTAAAGATGGTGAAGCTATCGTATTATCGAGTATTCCTTTTAATGCAAATTGGTTAAATCAACAATATGCTGAAATTATCCAAGCAATCTTATTTGATGTTGTAGGCTATGAAGTTAAACCTCACTTTATTACTCTGAAGAATTAGCAAATTATAGTAATAATGAAACTGCTACTCCAAAAGAAACAACAAAACCTTCTACTGAAACAACTGAGGATAATCATGTGCTTGGTAGAGAGCAATTCAATGCCCATAACACATTTGACACTTTTGTAATCGGACCCGGTAACCGCTTTCCACATGCAGCGAGTTTAGCTGTGGCCGAAGCACCAGCCAAAGCGTACAATCCATTATTTATCTATGGAGGTGTTGGTTTA

>Saureus1|SACOL0002
ATGATGGAATTCACTATTAAAAGAGATTATTTTATTACACAATTAAATGACACATTAAAAGCTATTTCACCAAGAACAACATTACCTATATTAACTGGTATCAAAATCGATGCGAAAGAACATGAAGTTATATTAACTGGTTCAGACTCTGAAATTTCAATAGAAATCACTATTCCTAAAACTGTAGATGGCGAAGATATTGTCAATATTTCAGAAACAGGCTCAGTAGTACTTCCTGGACGATTCTTTGTTGATATTATAAAAAAATTACCTGGTAAAGATGTTAAATTATCTACAAATGAACAATTCCAGACATTAATTACATCAGGTCATTCTGAATTTAATTTAAGTGGCTTAGATCCAGATCAATATCCTTTATTACCTCAAGTTTCTAGAGATG
```